# Layout not updating when changed during runtime

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I've got an ImageButton which I apply an OnClickListener to with the following code:

```
playButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.mainMenuPlayButton);
playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_startup_module);
    }
});
```

This works fine, as when I run the program on my android device and press the button, it instantly changes to the `activity_startup_module` layout. However, later on, in another class, I use the same method but instead apply the OnClickListener to a `RelativeLayout`:

```
startupLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.startupScreen);
startupLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu_module);
    }
});
```

When I try pressing on the `RelativeLayout` while running the code, the layout doesn't change until the screen orientation changes, at which point it updates and changes to the `activity_main_menu_module` layout.

I'd like to know why this is happening, and if there is something wrong with my code, or something I could add to force the layout to update straight away (as opposed to when the orientation changes)? It's entirely possible that I'm going about changing layouts the wrong way, given that this is my first Android Studio project. If it factors in in any way, the device I'm using to test the program is a 16GB Galaxy Tab 10.1 P7510.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You should use [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) instead of changing layouts (from what I can guess from your names)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use Fragments http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html here is link for developer.android.com, but if you want to change your layout with this code, please check is your R.id.startupScreen layout clickable

Comment: The problem was that the layout wasn't clickable, and it's working now, however I am probably going to switch over to using Fragments anyway, since that seems like a much better system. Thanks for the advice.